# Changing the transform: scale attribute using JavaScript in a working function

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, basically, I am creating a slide show, and want to hide my div's until the fluted button in the top left gets clicked it shows. When I try to change the `transform: scale()` of my DIV (dots) it just doesn't change even after I try to run the function. I tried to just use a normal regex to convert its scale but for some reason, it still doesn't change even after I put the function in the onClick attribute. Could somebody help with why it isn't working even after I did step-by-step trials? Thank you!!

```js
let slideIndex = 1;
//showSlides(slideIndex);




// Next/previous controls n = number selected in arrows
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(nu) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = nu);
}



function changeScale(newScale) {
  var div1 = document.getElementById("dot1");
  var div2 = document.getElementById("dot2");
  var div3 = document.getElementById("dot3");

  div1.style.transform = div1.style.transform.replace(/scale\([0-9|\.]*\)/, 'scale(' + newScale + ')');
  div2.style.transform = div2.style.transform.replace(/scale\([0-9|\.]*\)/, 'scale(' + newScale + ')');
  div3.style.transform = div3.style.transform.replace(/scale\([0-9|\.]*\)/, 'scale(' + newScale + ')');

}

function showSlides(n) {
  //makes i variable, gets slides and dots on slideshow
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");



  //n = number inputted/selected

  //dots.style.transform = dots.style.transform.replace(/scale\([0-9|\.]*\)/, 'scale(' + 1 + ')');



  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }

  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }




  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
.h2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 400px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  /*box-shadow: 0.6rem 0.6rem 1.9rem #525c5c, -0.5em -0.5em 1em #ffffff;
    */
  z-index: 100;
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
  /* ADD */
}

.wrapper:hover {
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 4px lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.wrapper .image {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* ADD */
  border-radius: 1rem;
  /* ADD */
}

.wrapper .image img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  /*REMOVE */
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  /* ADD */
}

.wrapper:hover img {
  /* change scale? */
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.wrapper .infocontent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-shadow: 0.5px 2px 10px rgba(214, 205, 205, 0.616);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Consolas;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #441d9e;
  cursor: pointer;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Hide the images by default */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover {
  background-color: rgba(53, 49, 49, 0.37);
}

.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(53, 49, 49, 0.37);
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

#dot1 {
  transform: scale(0);
}

#dot2 {
  transform: scale(0);
}

#dot3 {
  transform: scale(0);
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* .hide{
}
 */


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="h2">Flute</h1>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="image1.webp" title="Golden Flute Background (possibly article?)" onclick="currentSlide(1); changeScale(4); ">
  </div>
  <div class="infocontent">
    <h3><strong>Golden Flute</strong></h3>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img id="image" src="image1.webp" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <!-- <img src="img2.jpg" style="width:100%">-->
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <!--<img src="img3.jpg" style="width:100%"> -->
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">

  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)" id="dot1"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)" id="dot2"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)" id="dot3"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that `div1.style.transform` is an empty string in the beginning. Therefore the `replace` function doesn't find any matches to your regex that it could replace.
I don't see the necessity in using `replace` at all, you can just set the new value you want to have there. You could try it like this:

```
div1.style.transform = `scale(${newScale})`;
div2.style.transform = `scale(${newScale})`;
div3.style.transform = `scale(${newScale})`;
```

Comment: AHHH THANK YOU SO MUCH IT WORKED BEAUTIFULLY! I see what you are saying as well, and now that I think about it it makes a lot more sense. Thank you!!!!

Comment: do you mind upvoting my post I am trying to get a badge lol

Comment: Glad I could help you and I did upvote the post :)